# Conditional Statement in SharePoint Designer Workflow Not Working

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, workflow

For some reason this does not work.

[image]

Comment: Set to start workflow on item change

Answer (score 1):

Based on your workflow screenshot, these actions are run when the `Comment` is not empty.

[image]

Please check whether the `Comment` is empty when editing the item. if it is empty, these action will not be run.

And you should put the "`if Status Changed equals No`" condition and "`if Status Changed equals Yes`" condition outside the condition "`if current item:Status Before not equals current item:Request Status`". In your workflow, you set the `Status Changed` to `Yes` and then check  whether `Status Changed` is `Yes` or not. The "`if Status Changed equals Yes or No`" is useless as it is set to "Yes" in the above action.

[image]

You can try the following workflow:

[image]

if you want to check the Status changed when the Comment is not empty, move up check status actions under "set variable:Comment Copy to current Item:Comment" action.

[image]

By the way, you can use "log to History List" to debug the workflow. And Note that, if you are using a System Account, the workflow will not function properly or won’t start automatically.